# How to position an image next to text and scale it with screen resolution

Tags: html, css

I had a simple setup with a paragraph of text and an image to its right. The problem was that the picture's resolution would not change if the user had a smaller screen. I replaced "width: 256px" with "width: 40%" in the style. This made the image scale appropriately, but it moved up above the text. No matter how small I made the image, it would not pop back down. It did stay to the right, however.

Here is my html:

```html
<p style="float:right"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt="Missing Img" style="float:right; width: 40%"></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the wrapping `p` tag, or even place the `img` tag inside the text's `p` tag...
Something like this:

```html
<p>
  <img src="Url" alt="Missing Img" style="float:right; width: 40%"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</p>
```

Comment: Oh...Seems obvious now. I wrapped it like that while trying to figure out how to place the image to the right of the text before I looked it up. It never occurred to me to remove it when I learned about floating.